# Sequences that are subsequences of each other

Tags: real-analysis

I've been thinking about this problem for awhile now, but I still can't figure out part (b)... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(a) Find two distinct sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n$ is a subsequence of $b_n$ and $b_n$ is a subsequence of $a_n$.

(b) What if we also enforce the condition that $\{ a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ must be infinite?

I'm understanding "infinite" as unbounded right now. I don't know if that's actually the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), if $a_n$ and $b_n$ oscillate in some different way between two values, so that neither is eventually constant, you are there.  Can you see why?

The condition in (b) demands that $a_n$ must take an infinite number of distinct values.  You are correct that since the values are in $\Bbb N$ that means $a_n$ must be unbounded, but if the values were in $\Bbb R$ it would not.  For this problem it is not important.

You can get halfway there by making $b_{n+1}=a_n$ and choosing $b_1$ to be whatever you want.  Clearly $a_n$ is a subsequence of $b_n$.  Now if $a_n$ consists of a series of ramps, each higher than the last, then returns to $1$, so $1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$ you are home.

Comment: Thank you! The "ramps" technique was pretty clever.